# Adding Google Maps Activity gradle build permanent failure

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin

I have simply went through and attempted to add a a Google Map Activity in Android Studio, ie. Right click -> New -> Google -> Google Maps Activity,

Upon completion, the app attempted to build, and subsequently crashed during the build displaying the error:

`Gradle 'appname' project refresh failed`

`Error: exception during working with external systems`

Now, the src folder and manifest file have disappeared and any method including the most basic, `super.onCreate` display "Cannot resolve method"...

When attempting to clean the project it notes:

```
Error:The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\.....\appanme\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

The build.gradle (Project: appname) file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module: app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Additional
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Why would this happen? How can it be resolved?

**UPDATE**

AndroidManifest.xml: This code was merged with the manifest, breaking the app

```
  <<<<<<< Original
...
...
</manifest>

=======
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <activity android:name="com.example.socialActions.RestaurantLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_restaurant_location">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

Comment: As the message tells you, the problem is your manifest so you need to post it, make sure there's only one root element and that everything is nested correctly

Comment: @NickCardoso I updated the question with the manifest file

Comment: Why your manifest file has lines like "<<<<<<< Original", ">>>>>>> Added"? Try to remove all those things from your manifest file.

Comment: @rookiedev they were not there before the creation of the Google Maps Activity. Why would they be present now?

Comment: Merge conflicts when Android Studio went to add in the extra content.....

Comment: Is something like this a rare occurrence or should I just stay away from the automatic formulated activities

Comment: It's rare, and it's not a big deal.  Just fix the manifest when it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest has merge conflicts, review it and remove the <<<< parts and any duplicate / outdated info. Alternately if you're in Android studio you should be able to view file history and revert to an earlier version if you are confused.

Comment: How can I revert to older file history?

Comment: Open the file, Right click the tab with the filename (AndroidManifest.xml), Local history -> show history. Find the correct version and use the purple button (top left) or manually copy changes over